# Trigger for update audit table with new and old values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two tables one Products and Products_audit and I want to use Products_audit like audit table so I want to use trigger After Update. I wrote trigger but can't understand how to joing two tables 'Inserted' and 'Deleted'

```
CREATE TRIGGER Super2
ON Products
AFTER Update
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Products_audit

      (ProductID,
       ProductName,
       SupplierID,
       CategoryID,
       QuantityPerUnit,
       UnitPrice,
       UnitsInStock,
       UnitsOnOrder,
       ReorderLevel,
       Discontinued,
       Date,
       [User])

SELECT 

       ProductID,
       ProductName,
       SupplierID,
       CategoryID,
       QuantityPerUnit,
       UnitPrice,
       UnitsInStock,
       UnitsOnOrder,
       ReorderLevel,
       Discontinued,
       getdate(),
       suser_sname()

       FROM deleted

inserted 
    inner join deleted d on i.id = d.id

      END
```

Please help me write lastes strings

```
FROM deleted
inserted 
    inner join deleted d on i.id = d.id

      END
```

Cause I didn't get how to write them in correct way.

Comment: If you just want to write the *old* values to the table, why do you need to join to `inserted` at all? If the table has a column called `id` then it looks right except you have an extra `inserted` between `deleted` and `inner join`. Otherwise your join should probably be on `ProductID` not `id`.

Comment: I want to write new values as well

Comment: Then shouldn't your audit table have more columns, e.g. OldProductName, NewProductName? Or columns to indicate old row / new row? Also what is the point of recording the new value in the audit table? You can always see what the new value was later by joining to the base table (when the update was the last one) or joining to the next "old value" in the audit table (when the update you're investigating was not the last one).

Comment: nope I want to see them just by order in audit table. Man please write how should look my trigger in ending view.

Comment: As Aaron pointed out, your schema would need to be different. IMO the most useful audit tables just have previous values, as well as change-metadata like 'edit date', 'deleted date' etc. Simply insert the 'deleted' values into the audit table, and you're set.

Comment: I still don't follow. If someone updates 5 rows, you're going to write 10 rows to the audit table? How are you going to be able to distinguish the old rows from the new rows? They're all going to have the same value for `getdate()`. And remember that a table is an unsorted set of rows, by definition. So "by order in audit table" makes little sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so if all you want to do is place both the old and new versions of the row into the audit table, then you don't want a `JOIN`, you want a `UNION ALL`.

(As I mentioned in my comments above, I do not understand this logic at all, and I guarantee you will change this later when you realize how wrong it is.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Super2
ON dbo.Products FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.Products_audit
  (
       ProductID,
       ...other columns...,
       Date,
       [User]
  )
  SELECT 
       ProductID,
       ...other columns...,
       getdate(),
       suser_sname()
    FROM deleted -- <--- ****** deleted ******
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
       ProductID,
       ...other columns...,
       getdate(),
       suser_sname()
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

What I think you need is an additional column, at the very least, on your audit table, indicating "before update" and "after update." Let's call it `ChangeStatus` (which you could also re-use for your insert and delete operations):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Super2
ON dbo.Products FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE(), @u SYSNAME = SUSER_SNAME();

  INSERT dbo.Products_audit
  (
       ProductID,
       ...other columns...,
       ChangeStatus,
       Date,
       [User]
  )
  SELECT 
       ProductID,
       ...other columns...,
       'before update',
       @d,
       @u
    FROM deleted -- <--- ****** deleted ******
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
       ProductID,
       ...other columns...,
       'after update',
       @d,
       @u
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Comment: And where table deleted ? How to obtain values from there ?

Comment: *sigh* please look closer. I've added a highlight to make it obvious where the `deleted` pseudo-table is referenced. If you mean something else (e.g. how do I audit when a row is deleted?) then please be more specific.

Comment: Greate Man everything is working ! Thanks a bunch !!! I just was needed statement UNION ALL !!!